# TkFileDialog.askopenfilenames() order different than order of selection

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've noticed that the returned list from a `tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames()` doesn't match the order you selected the files. In fact, the last selected file appears first! Followed by the other selected files in correct order.

Example given: when having 4 files: `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt` and `file4.txt`;

- When selecting `file1` to `file4` you get: `file4.txt`, `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`.
- When selecting `file1` and then `file 2`, you get: `file2.txt`, `file1.txt`
- When selecting `file1` to `file3`, you get: `file3.txt`, `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`

You can see the string building up in the dialog when selecting the files.

This behaviour is quite irritating for me, because I use the order of selection to plot all data in one plot. Due to this behaviour I end up with a legend where the last file is the first one followed by sequentially correctly listed the other files.

Does someone know how to tackle this problem? I know I can sort the resulting list, but given the fact that I might later on want to select e.g. `file2`, `file3`, `file1` and `file4`. I can't always apply this trick.

The code to reproduce this behaviour:

```
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()

myList = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title='Choose a file')
```

Comment: It seems that it's Tk which does the ordering, not python, as the filenames are ordered while still in the dialog, so you may have to do a bit of reimplementation to stop sorting.

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, but you can always convert the output tuple to a list using `list(myList)` and use `myList.append(myList.pop(0))` to place the first item in the list at the back.

Comment: There could well be a dictionary underneath this, so there's no reason to expect order. If the order in which files are selected matters, the user should pick them one-at-a-time, I would certainly never expect a multi-file selector to respect the order they were chosen.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, its Tk/Tcl doing the weird ordering, not python. Looks like there isn't a way to fix this, except reimplementation / use something else like Qt.

Comment: Either way, I'm not sure it makes UX sense to expect order from a multi-file selector, and I doubt many implementations would guarantee it.

Comment: Thank you all very much. This clears up a lot. I'll use fhdrsdg's suggestion. Although I'm getting used to pick the first file last, I'm sure another user won't neith will I in a year.

Comment: There are definitely use-cases when the file selection order matters (e.g. merging PDF files) and @fhdrsdg's suggestion works a treat.