# PySimpleGui Input + FilesBrowse auto ordering selected files

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Using PySimpleGUI, I'm doing a layout with the following line:

```
[Sg.Text("Images:", size=(6, 1)), Sg.Input(key='-IN0-', change_submits=True, size=(64, 1)),
           Sg.FilesBrowse('Select')]
```

The problem is that in the GUI, when I select a list of files (ctrl+mouse click in the selection window), the list apears ordered by name in the Sg.Input element (and so in the '-IN0-' value) but in my program the order of file selection is important. Searched in PySimpleGUI cookbook and found nothing. Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782208/tkfiledialog-askopenfilenames-order-different-than-order-of-selection

Answer (score 0):

I see two answers to this question, one would be to ask the user to add individually by calling the window repeatedly with a different key, or to get the user to assign some sort of order variable to them?